# Instagram Graph API Unknown error fetching conversations

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I followed all of the steps in the getting started page from the Instagram Messaging docs found here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/get-started). I even enabled message control tools and was able to successfully perform GET requests on all steps mentioned in the docs except for GETing the conversations? from the Graph API.

My request was
curl -i -X GET
"https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/xxxxx/conversations?platform=instagram&access_token=EAA..."

And my response was

```
HTTP/2 500 
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
access-control-allow-origin: *
facebook-api-version: v13.0
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
x-fb-request-id: AWxxxx
x-fb-trace-id: Gxxxxx
x-fb-rev: 1xxxxx
x-fb-debug: Icxxxxx
content-length: 77
date: Tue, 21 Jun 2022 04:11:42 GMT
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400

{"error":{"code":1,"message":"An unknown error occurred","error_subcode":99}}
```

I'm wondering why since I followed everything up to here and it was working. Any suggestions on what I could've missed or did wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Missing permissions can cause this issue. It is listed as the first issue under the [error codes section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/error-codes). Make sure you give the user access token appropriate permissions before you create the token. It says moderate but the permissions required are:

From Facebook Login:

1. instagram_basic
2. instagram_manage_messages
3. pages_manage_metadata

**Remember, your Facebook Developer account must be able to perform Tasks with atleast "Moderate" level access on the Facebook Page connected to the Instagram account you want to query.**